# Oracle apex value of item is not up-to-date in button link builder when using redirect to another page

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-19.1

I have a value of a field on page 1 that I need to pass to page 2 (modal dialog).
The field is changed on page 1. and I can see it's got updated on the page and when I print its value in debug messages.

When I'm clicking the button, with the action "Redirect to Page in application", the value on page 2 is the initial value of the field, and not the updated one, is this a bug?

[image]

what can I do?

I don't want to use dynamic action or things like "prepare_url" because of many reasons.
Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

That is not how a link works. What you are seeing is not a bug, it is expected behaviour. The link is rendered when the page is rendered and will have the item values at render time and a calculated checksum (depends on settings) based on those values. It will not pick up any changes.

The "traditional" way to do this is the following. Assumptions: Need to navigate from page 1 to page 2 and set P2_ITEM on page 2 to value of P1_ITEM on page 1.

1. Create button (let's say button name is MYBUTTON) of type "Submit Page"
2. Under "Processing", create a branch to page 2.
3. For "Page or URL" pick page 2 and set P2_ITEM to value P1_ITEM.
4. For "Process point" pick "After Submit"
5. Under "Server Side Condition", select "MYBUTTON" under "When Button Pressed".

Since this is a branch your page has been submitted and all the changes you made to P1_ITEM will be picked up. The fact that page 2 is modal does not affect this, APEX will take care of that for you.

Comment: So the only way to do so is by submitting the page? There is no way to render / refresh only the button?

Comment: You can most probably do it with a dynamic action as well, but that will be more complicated, since you need the prepare the url. You stated that you don't want to do that.

Comment: it really works, thank you.  but after did that, I encounter another issue. because I open the dialog window with the branch, I am unable to refresh the current page region(eg. a IG) after the dialog close by adding a close-dialog dynamic action on the button. how can get the callback from closing of dialog which is open from the branch but not a button.

Comment: Thanks Koen, I needed to disable "Value Protected" for item using in link.

Comment: Koen, My life is better because of your post. Your post solved this problem for me and I wasted hours unsuccessfully fiddling in Apex trying to figure it out without success. Thanks for sharing a very simple step-by-step posting. You deserve a hug.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to Koen Lostries excellent explanation, in some cases it is also possible to have the target page load the item from the source page.

Ensure that the item is being pushed to the session, for example by using a dynamic action with the `items to submit` option, but do nothing else in this dynamic action.
Then, when page 2 opens, simply add a pre-header-process, that makes something like `:P2_ITEM := :P1_ITEM;`

In my experience this approach is easier than doing a redirect in a dynamic action, as there is no declarative option for that and you often need hand-written javascript to do that.

Comment: I also thought of this solution, unfortunately I have about 20 pages with the button that redirect to page 2, some of the buttons are inside interactive reports (that's also why I wanted to avoid Dynamic action, which will require me to use javascript) and some inside the page, so I can't use the source page's items.

Comment: For this case, add an item like `P2_SOURCE_PAGE` to your target page. In your link, transmit the page number of the source page. Then, your pre header process on the target page can have a `case when` that distinguished between the calling pages and load the appropriate data into your item.

Answer (score 0):

You can also check after a modal window was closed using Koen's solution by creating a dynamic action with a dialog closed or cancelled dynamic action with a JS Expression selection type of 'window'.